# Ratingbar on App Widget, is there a way to insert it?

Tags: android, widget, android-widget, ratingbar

I know that Rating bar is not in the list of remoteView compatibile classes, but I saw some widget with a rating bar working fine, how is it possible?

Should I simulate it with some star buttons?
Thanks

Comment: were you able to actually submit a rating? my guess would be no. If a user is working with the rating bar within the application,  you can include a rating bar and call a function to get the rating from the app and update the rating on the widget. ive done it with progress bar.

Comment: @Droidev tanks. I will try the progress bar. But my scope is to give the possibility to rate the object directly from the widget in addition to the app, is it possible?

Comment: no, that is not possible to do. however, if you want, when the user clicks the widget, you can deeplink into an activity in your app for the user to rate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in a bad way. I put on the widget a button (with a star drawable) for each star in need in the rating bar, then for each button star I give different OnClickListeners that corresponds to the star number. For example, the first star button has the OnclickLister 'firstStarPressed'. In this method the button star drawable is updated to a filled star drawable.
I got rid of ugly, but it works